C# method in Aras Innovator returning null value
I have a C# method (server side) in Aras Innovator to write some of the properties in an item type to a pdf. I recently tried to add another row to a table in the pdf similarily how I added other properties but it is defaulted to the placeholder or "N/A" even though the property has a value.
 string classi = quote.getPropertyAttribute("classification", "keyed_name", "N/A");
 gsarow = gsaTable.AddRow();
 gsarow.Height = "0.6cm";
 gsarow.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Classification");
 gsarow.Cells[0].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
 gsarow.Cells[0].Format.Font.Bold = true;
 gsarow.Cells[1].AddParagraph(classi);
 gsarow.Cells[1].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;

The above is all I have added. It currently returns "Classification:  N/A" in the PDF. Not sure why classification would be different from getting other Aras properties but I could see it being. Any help would be appreciated.
I tried doing a little more research into the data type of the classification property because it isn't as clear as other ones you set like strings and floats.

Try retrieving the property by
string classi = Path.GetFileName(quote.getProperty("classification"));

above will return the last substring.
or
string classi = quote.getProperty("classification", "N/A");

Hopefully this helps
